# ¿Cómo posicionar la leyenda lateral de un gráfico usando ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
label_data1 <- data.frame(Gráfica_1_Tabla_1)
id <- seq(1:43) 
label_data1$id <- id 
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data1) 
# -----------------------------------------------------------

angulo <- 90 - 360 * (label_data1$id - 0.5) / number_of_bar
label_data1$hjust <- ifelse(angulo < -90, 1.1, -0.1) 
label_data1$angulo <- ifelse(angulo < -90, angulo + 180, angulo)

# ---------------------------------------------------
grafica1 <- ggplot(Gráfica_1_Tabla_1, aes(x = as.factor(label_data1$id), 
  y = label_data1$Recursos.actuales, fill = label_data1$Tipo.de.repositorio)) + 

  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  ylim(-600, 578) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(), 
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1, 4), "cm")
  ) +
  coord_polar(start = 0) + 
  geom_text(data = label_data1, aes(x = label_data1$id, y = label_data1$Recursos.actuales, 
                                   label = label_data1$concat, hjust=hjust), color="black", 
            fontface="bold",alpha=1.0, size=2.5,angle = label_data1$angulo, 
            inherit.aes = FALSE)

grafica1
```

[image: Gráfico Circular]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes establecer las posiciones de la leyenda mediante [`theme()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.1.0/topics/theme). Supongamos un gráfico como el siguiente:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = cut, fill = color)) + 
        geom_bar(colour= "black", size = 0.3 ) +  
        coord_polar()

p
```

Por defecto las leyendas se mostrarán a la derecha en forma vertical, si quiséramos modificar estas para que se vean de forma horizontal en la parte superior o inferior podemos hacer:

```
# En la parte superior
p + theme(legend.position="top") + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))

# En la parte inferior
p + theme(legend.position="bottom") + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

Con `guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))` intentamos al menos que todas las leyendas se vean en una sola fila y por supuesto con `theme(legend.position="top")`establecemos la posición, las posibles obviamente son: `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` y  `none`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, puedes además establecer la posición de forma manual con un vector de dos elementos, por ej.:

```
p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Patricio muchas gracias por tu respuesta, soy nuevo usuario de R y no encontraba como mover la leyenda de la gráfica. Muchas gracias !!